# What outlook API do you use for seeing busy/free subject location

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api

What APIs can i use to see

1. busy/free times of a contact that I'm trying to schedule with.
2. If the contact has subject and location visible, I'd want to have access to that information too.

(Much like the "scheduling" wizard in the outlook desktop application)

I tried /users/Id/events ... I can't access other users events of course. 
I tried calendarview with just start and end.  403. Forbidden on other users calendars.

I do have granted Calendars.Read scope in my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graph includes functionality specifically for [finding meeting times](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/findmeetingtimes_example). You pass it a set of constrains (location, time window, etc.) and a list of attendees and it returns a list of available meeting times.

Comment: Thanks. So nothing to explicitly see what time a person is free/busy ? like in the Schedlung section ? Please see this : https://ibb.co/eKPwZk

Comment: That is correct. That classic Free/Busy dialog is actually more restrictive in that it assumes you have permission to see the attendee's free/busy data and scopes everything to your time zone. It also places the burden of sorting out the best time on the organizer. Find Meeting Times provides a richer result set and reduces the burden placed on the user.