# How to get free and busy rooms details in microsoft graph API for particular time period?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is there any microsoft office graph API available where I can get available and busy meeting room details.

My requirement is that I will pass some start date time and end date time and expect all the available and busy room list.

As for as I know we can add room outlook portal admin section.

I have gone through below findRoomLists and findrooms API they are just giving rooms information not there status busy/free.
I want status also Is there any functionality available in graph API.

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/findRoomLists
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/findRooms
Have gone through below link but no help.

[How to display a list of available meeting rooms at present using Microsoft Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46139426/how-to-display-a-list-of-available-meeting-rooms-at-present-using-microsoft-grap)

[Can't get all busy times of meeting rooms using the Office365 Calendar API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42466839/cant-get-all-busy-times-of-meeting-rooms-using-the-office365-calendar-api)

Thanks
Ajay Tiwari

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45203738/what-outlook-api-do-you-use-for-seeing-busy-free-subject-location

Answer (score 5):

After searching a lot I found Microsoft has an API to do this thing. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-getschedule?view=graph-rest-beta

Description says

> Get the free/busy availability information for a collection of users, distributions lists, or resources, for a specified time period.

There's one catch though, it is in beta you have to be careful to use it in production. But for now it is working great.